# ASP.NET Core error on Build - One or more compilation references are missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been having a lot of problems with my ASP.NET Core Web App. It started when I was using Add-Migration, I was getting a lot of errors. Then when I tried to fix that I began getting errors with ASP.NET Core. I updated Visual Studio as well. Used `dotnet restore` as mentioned on another question. Now when I run my project, I get the following Internal server error page

[image: One or more compilation references are missing.]

Even now if I run Add-Migration I get a lot of errors ending with: `The current CSharpHelper cannot scaffold literals of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.DirectConstructorBinding'. Configure your services to use one that can.`

NuGet Packages:

- **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design** (up to date)
- **Microsoft.NETCore.App** (up to date)
- **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** (up to date)
- **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore** (up to date)
- **Microsoft.AspNetCore.All** (Can't update past 2.0.8)

Trying to update the last one to latest gives me the error: `Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)`

**EDIT:** Added `<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" **Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web**">` and `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>` to the .csproj.user file and the project does not load in visual studio, giving the error:

```
Importing the file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\Sdk\Sdk.targets" into the file "C:\Users\(User)\Documents\WebPortal\WebPortal.csproj.user" results in a circular dependency.
```

Comment: As a first step, have you followed the steps in the error message and checked that you have `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` as the first line of your .csproj file, and `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>` set? You won't be able to update to `2.1.x` unless you update your SDK to at least 
`2.1.300` and haven't pinned the runtime in the `global.json` in the solution root if you have one.

Comment: @MartinCostello I added those to the .csproj.user file and now the project won't load at all, see the edit to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to manually install latest SDK and Runtime manually from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks). Then restart visual studio. Once restarted, go to .csproj file (or right-click the solution and click properties), go to the Application Tab, and change the "Target Framework" to the latest (which you just installed).